# Django Model.objects.all().delete() not completing

Tags: python, mysql, django, django-models

I have a django app which deletes all the entries in a db and then enters another set. I am having a problem where `Model.objects.all().delete()` leaves objects in the database (The same entries every time).

I have fixed it using this code:

```
db_events = Event.objects.all()
while db_events.count():
    db_events.delete()
```

Clearly this is not a great fix. What is going on and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have found that delete doesn't work very well for large querysets. It seems to generate individual deletes for each object/row. In one instance where I had to delete millions of rows it would time out before completing. Since it would always time out at at the same point the same rows would remain. The answer was to write raw sql. Something like

```
Event.objects.raw('DELETE FROM myapp_event')
```

I'm not certain this is what is happening to you though. But it is one possible option. The provided SQL is valid for Postgresql and MySQL. Others may differ. Consult your documentation. Also, most databases have a TRUNCATE command that is quicker. It would look like:

```
Event.objects.raw('TRUNCATE myapp_event')
```

You'll have to look up your table name. **generally** they will be `<django_app_name>_<model_name>` lowercased. Note the django app name is not the overall app name. It's the sub app.